# How to create links to lists in my custom global navigation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, css, html, global-navigation

[image: My edit page]

Created a global Navigation with drop down menu but not sure how to create links in my code to my SP lists. Here is a link to my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/XPE3w/2738/

Answer (score 0):

you can give the address of your required sp list in every link as shown below

```
 <li><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">The Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://rediffmail.com" target=' _blank">History</a></li>
```

Comment: Great thanks it worked! I guess my last question would be do yo know why my code puts red blocks around my edit page. I posted a pic to let you know what I'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

And for the Red background problem
I would try 4 places:

First, Navigate to the Edit page in IE and use Developer Tools; click HTML tab on left of screen, then Style on the right.

Alternately,

- Open Master Page in SharePoint Designer; look for any reference to
  CSS files or CSS code.
- Open any custom CSS files you find in SPD and check.
- Open your Edit page in SPD and check.

Most probably you have custom CSS file which is causing this issue.

This might be the place where the problem resides:  
`<DIV id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Caption_ctl00_nativeHtmlEditorContainer style="PADDING-RIGHT: 30px; PADDING-LEFT: 30px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 30px; PADDING-TOP: 30px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: red">`

Best bet is to navigate to the Edit page in IE and use Developer Tools to help track the source for the above code.